# Using MemoryDescriptor (for new WebAssembly.Memory()) in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, webassembly

I'm trying to use the following code:

```
const test = new WebAssembly.Memory({initial : 2, shared : true, maximum : 3});
```

IntelliSense in VS Code says everything is good.
And I can run that code directly in Chrome's JavaScript console.
But when I try to run `tsc` I get the following error:
[image]

I right clicked in VS Code.
It has the expected definitions in `lib.dom.ts.d`.

```
var Memory: {
    prototype: Memory;
    new(descriptor: MemoryDescriptor): Memory;
};
interface MemoryDescriptor {
    initial: number;
    maximum?: number;
    shared?: boolean;
}
```

However, I see 7 copies of `lib.dom.ts.d` on my computer.
(There were 6 before I upgraded to the latest version of typescript.)
Based on the file sizes there are at least three different versions of this file.

**Is there a way to fix this?**

I have a workaround, but it's ugly.
If I cast to `any` it works fine.

```
const test = new WebAssembly.Memory({initial : 2, shared : true, maximum : 3} as any);
```

Answer (score 0):

the `shared` property was missing in [TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator), but last month (Feb/2021) someone added it to the `MemoryDescriptor` interface ([pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator/pull/967)), you can use the latest version or re-write it until the stable version is released.

e.g:

```
interface SharedMemoryDescriptor {
    initial: number;
    maximum?: number;
    shared?: boolean;
}

const test = new WebAssembly.Memory({initial : 2, shared : true, maximum : 3} as SharedMemoryDescriptor);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll grab the latest TypeScript from github.